# Find hard-coded values - connection string, hostname and URI in .Net code

Tags: .net, vb.net, sonarqube, resharper, code-analysis

I have a .Net application that contains VB project and web site codebase. There are few hardcoded values such as connection string, hostnames and URI in the source the code. I am trying to find out a tool that detects all of them. I have tried SonarVB and Resharper. But they are not able to capture the hardcoded values. Please suggest if there are any other alternatives. Here is the sample code snippet in .vb file.

```
      Dim dbCon As String = "server=########;database=testdb01;uid=user1;pwd=Password01"

Dim blnAuthenticated As Boolean
        blnAuthenticated = AuthenticateUser("LDAP://#########.net", txtId.Text.Trim, txtPassword.Text.Trim)
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any specific tool and that's not what this site is for anyway but I would think that a few Find In Files involving a double quote should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the response. There are so many files in the codebase. This has to be done for all the applications as we are migrating. Find can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper 5 is obvious a choice.

1. Turn on solution wide analysis.
2. Go to `ReSharper|Options|Code Inspection|Inspection Severity|Potential Code Quality Issues|Element is localizable` set to `Show as error`.
3. Go back to Solution Explorer and click on the project (csproj).
4. In Properties panel under ReSharper category, set Localizable to Yes, Localizable Inspector to Pessimistic.

Then you can find almost all you need in Errors in Solution panel.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is exactly what I did for Resharper. But it didn't work!

Comment: Resource Refactoring Tool provides developers an easy way to extract hard coded strings from the code to resource files.  try this https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=resourcerefactoring